# stack pop not returning

Tags: lisp, stack

I'm trying to branch out and learn lisp.  One of the basics would be to implement a simple stack.  Everything works but my `pop` function.

```
;Returns and removes the first element of the stack
(defun my-pop ()
    (let (temp (car *stack*))
    (setq *stack* (cdr *stack*))
    temp))
```

This correctly removes the "top" of the stack, but does not return it.  Earlier, I had this:

```
;Returns and removes the first element of the stack
(defun my-pop ()
    (print (car *stack*)
    (setq *stack* (cdr *stack*)))
```

But I'd rather return the top.

What am I doing wrong?  (I assume this has something to do with scope...)

Comment: It should be noted that `pop` and `push` are already defined in the standard.

Comment: @Svante it should also be noted that the question begins with "I'm trying to branch out and learn lisp. One of the basics would be to implement a simple stack."  (that's why it's named `my-pop`)

Comment: that's why I said "it should be noted" and not "read the fine manual".  I don't want people to search for "stack common lisp" and then think they have to implement it for themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to do with scope, it's a syntax problem.  The syntax of LET is:

```
(let ((var1 val1)
      (var2 val2)
      ...)
  body)
```

Additionally, a `(varN valN)` may be abbreviated to just `varN`, which is equivalent to `(varN nil)`. So what you wrote is equivalent to:

```
(let ((temp nil)     ; bind TEMP to NIL
      (car *stack*)) ; bind CAR to value of *STACK*
  (setq *stack* (cdr *stack*))
  temp)
```

You need an extra set of parentheses in your LET-bindings:

```
(let ((temp (car *stack*)))
  (setq *stack* (cdr *stack*))
  temp)
```

You could also use the built-in operator PROG1:

```
(prog1 
  (car *stack*)
  (setq *stack* (cdr *stack)))
```

Comment: Awesome.  Do you have a link to details on `prog1`?  (I'm having trouble finding a good source for docs)

Comment: Common Lisp Hyperspec: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check this when I get back to my dorm, then accept it.